# Compare GridView images on item click at run time in android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm developing a Memory Board game. Here are the rules: At first, cards are faced down. When a user clicks the first card it flips, when user clicks the second card it also flips and at this point these two cards are compared to each other. If they're same they're taken off the board, if not they'll be faced down again.

I have a GridView and implemented flipping and comparison of cards within "onItemClick" but I dont get the desired outcome as comparison outcome always mask the flipping of second card.

For example if the two are card matched they disappear as soon as the second card is clicked before user gets a chance to view the second card therefore understands there was a match. If they're not a match they've both get turned back again before user gets a chance to see the second card. I know there is a better way to get this done however I'm running out of ideas. Your help is much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
public class MemoryGridViewActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG="MemoryGridView";
    private static final Integer[] images = {R.drawable.image_0, R.drawable.image_1,R.drawable.image_0, R.drawable.image_1};
    private static final Integer coverImageId = R.drawable.back;
    List<Card> Cards;

    private GridView boardGridView;
    private CardAdapter mCardAdapter;
    private int numClick = 0;
    private int firstClick = -1;
    private int secondClick= -1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i=0; i < images.length; i++){
        Card tmpCard = new Card(images[i]);
        Cards.add(tmpCard);
    }

    boardGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    mCardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this, Cards);
    boardGridView.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);
    boardGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            numClick++;
            Card myCard = Cards.get(position);
            if (!myCard.getState()){
                myCard.setState(true);
                ImageView cardImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
                cardImage.setImageResource(myCard.getImageId());
            }

            if(numClick %2 != 0){
                firstClick = position;
                Log.i(TAG, "first card turned up. firstClick = "+firstClick+" secondClick = "+secondClick);

            }else{
                secondClick = position;
                Log.i(TAG, "second card turned up. firstClick = "+firstClick+" secondClick = "+secondClick);
            }
            //compare two cards
            if(firstClick != -1 && secondClick!= -1) {
                Card firstCard = Cards.get(firstClick);
                Card secondCard = Cards.get(secondClick);
                if(firstCard.getImageId()== secondCard.getImageId()){
                    Log.i(TAG,"two cards are the same");
                    parent.getChildAt(firstClick).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    parent.getChildAt(secondClick).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "two cards are different");
                    firstCard.setState(false);
                    ImageView cardImage1 = (ImageView) parent.getChildAt(firstClick).findViewById(R.id.cardView);
                    cardImage1.setImageResource(coverImageId);

                    secondCard.setState(false);
                    ImageView cardImage2 = (ImageView) parent.getChildAt(secondClick).findViewById(R.id.cardView);
                    cardImage2.setImageResource(coverImageId);
                    firstClick = secondClick = -1;

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the Card.java class

```
    public class Card{

     private static final String TAG="Card";
     private int imageId;
     private boolean state = false;

     public Card(int img_id){
         this.imageId = img_id;
     }

     public void setImageId (int img_id){
         this.imageId = img_id;
     }

     public int getImageId(){
         return imageId;
     }

     public boolean getState(){
         return state;
     }
     public void setState(boolean flag){
         this.state = flag;
     }
```

finally here is the CardAdapter.java

```
public class CardAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 private static final String TAG = "CardAdapter";
 private static final int PADDING= 8;
 private static final int WIDTH = 200;
 private static final int HEIGHT = 200;

 private Context mContext;
 private List<Card> mThumbIds;
 private int coverImageId = R.drawable.back;

public CardAdapter(Context c, List<Card> ids){
    this.mContext = c;
    this.mThumbIds = ids;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){ return mThumbIds.size();}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return mThumbIds.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
        return  position;}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //Log.i(TAG, "Entered getView");
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // Inflate the View for this Card from Card.xml
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card, null);
        convertView.setPadding(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Fill in the Card data
        Card tmpCard = (Card) getItem(position);
        if (!tmpCard.getState()) {
            holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(coverImageId);
        }else{
            holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(tmpCard.getImageId());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        numClick++;
        Card myCard = Cards.get(position);
        if (!myCard.getState()){
            myCard.setState(true);
            ImageView cardImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            cardImage.setImageResource(myCard.getImageId());
        }

        if(numClick %2 != 0){
            firstClick = position;
            Log.i(TAG, "first card turned up. firstClick = "+firstClick+" secondClick = "+secondClick);

        }else{
            secondClick = position;
            Log.i(TAG, "second card turned up. firstClick = "+firstClick+" secondClick = "+secondClick);
        }

        mCardAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

        if (firstClick != -1 && secondClick != -1) {
        new CountDownTimer(TIME_DELAY, DURATION_OF_TICK) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

                Card firstCard = Cards.get(firstClick);
                Card secondCard = Cards.get(secondClick);
                if (firstCard.getImageId() == secondCard.getImageId()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "two cards are the same");
                    parent.getChildAt(firstClick).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    parent.getChildAt(secondClick).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "two cards are different");
                    firstCard.setState(false);
                    ImageView cardImage1 = (ImageView) parent.getChildAt(firstClick).findViewById(R.id.cardView);
                    cardImage1.setImageResource(coverImageId);

                    secondCard.setState(false);
                    ImageView cardImage2 = (ImageView) parent.getChildAt(secondClick).findViewById(R.id.cardView);
                    cardImage2.setImageResource(coverImageId);
                    firstClick = secondClick = -1;

                    mCardAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                }
        }
    }.start();
   }
```

where TIME_DELAY is the duration for which you want to display the opened cards. You can put any value in DURATION_OF_TICK.

Comment: thank you so much @RJain90. It worked :) first time reaching out to community and I'm so happy I did.